# How can I subtract 1 from the previous index number in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, indexing

How can I subtract 1 (or any number) from the index without decrementing it (without it's value changing in the variable) ?

Here's a snippet of my code:

```
if (i > 0 & areaImages[i].id == areaImages[i-1].id)
```

And I get this error message from Firebug:

```
TypeError: areaImages[i - 1] is undefined
```

Comment: Consider using http://jshint.com to warn you about common mistakes like this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Nothing is decremented. The actual reason is you used the wrong operator.

```
if (i > 0 && areaImages[i].id == areaImages[i-1].id)
//        ^^
```

For booleans, both `&` and `&&` will return same (up to `==`) result. But the crucial difference is that `&&` is [short-circuiting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation), i.e. when the left-hand-side of `&&` is `false`, then the right-hand-side will not be evaluated.

The problem of the original code is that `&` is *not* short-circuiting, so `areaImages[i-1].id` will be evaluated even if `i <= 0`. But `i-1` is an invalid index, so `areaImages[i-1]` is undefined, and you cannot get a property from undefined, causing the TypeError.

Comment: Ok so `&&` is short-circuiting when the left-hand-side of `&&` is false. That was useful information. But how do I make `areaimages[i-1]`  a valid index? I just want to use the previous index without decrementing the `var i `

Comment: Continuing from where I left off above ^. Is `areaImages[-1]` the incorrect way to access the previous index or am I getting an undefined error message because that index is undefined at that moment in the program?

Comment: @Alexander: What do you expect `areaImages[-1]` to be?

Comment: It's been many months since I was working with this code so I can't remember and I can't find the code. So I'm just wondering if `arrayName[-1]` is the correct way to look at the previous array index?